# How can I debug scala source code in IDEA with SBT Jetty-run?

Tags: debugging, jetty, sbt

I found related answer in [Debugging Scala code with simple-build-tool (sbt) and IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150776/debugging-scala-code-with-simple-build-tool-sbt-and-intellij) . But I still don't get it. Does it mean I need to first config the following in sbt.bat
set SCRIPT_DIR=%~dp0
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -Xmx512M -jar "%SCRIPT_DIR%sbt-launch-0.7.5.RC0.jar" %* 
And then launch the "Remote" in Run/Debug configurations in IDEA all with default?
After those two steps, the program can stop in the breakpoint when I refresh my web application page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging Scala code with simple-build-tool (sbt) and IntelliJ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150776/debugging-scala-code-with-simple-build-tool-sbt-and-intellij)

Answer (score 1):

See my answer in the related question:

[Debugging Scala code with simple-build-tool (sbt) and IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150776/debugging-scala-code-with-simple-build-tool-sbt-and-intellij/6131737#6131737)