# How to create an SBT Run configuration in IntelliJ IDEA 11 Community Edition?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, lift, sbt, jrebel

I have created a Lift project ifor IDEA 11 Community Edition using an sbt-idea plugin.
It compiles and runs well from SBT plugins SBT console, I`m also able to debug it via creating right "Remote" configuration.

**But how do I create an SBT Run configuration?**

I don't want to type each time "container:start" in SBT console, I want to startup using a Run/Debug button.
I was unable to find some SBT configuration type (like there is available a "Maven" type), and when I try to add configuration based on "Application type" I cannot specify the main class.

There is also **no "Scala Compilation Server" type available** (I cannot see it in the list of available configuration types), so I cannot use solutions like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6131737/705819/
Are there any specific actions that should be done for the "Scala Compilation Server" type to show up? Or does it available only in the full edition of IDEA?

**UPDATE:** I`m also using JRebel for my project. Without proper run configuration I have to run SBT with JRebel via VM parameters and debug via Remote configuration - so it makes me to restart debugger each time I update the code (cause Jrebel reloads the class) instead of just clicking "Debug with Jrebel" button (thanks to the Jrebel IDEA plugin). It is very annoying, please help!

Comment: Add `alias cs=container:start` to `.sbtrc` to avoid a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much of the servlet container do you need? I would recommend to write a normal main method that starts an embedded Jetty.

Add this to your build settings to add Jetty to the test classpath:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mortbay.jetty" % "jetty" % "6.1.22" % "test"
```

Then take a [code snippet from here](http://irc.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty) to start Jetty:

You can set up a [pre-run action](https://github.com/orfjackal/idea-sbt-plugin/wiki) for this Run Configuration to run `sbt package`, which will create a the WAR.

Comment: Thanks alot! I wrote a main method for jetty 8 (api has slightly changed http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty) and it worked!

The last thing - I`m still using an SBT console in parallel with debugging (I run "~compile" command), cause JRebel requires continious compilation of the sources for its proper work. I was hoping that I can assign a before launch SBT Action "~compile", but there is no such an option. Maybe you can suggest a workaround for it?

Comment: I have the same problem, bit this solution did not work for me, because I do not write a web application at all.