# debug scala code in intellij?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I just join a team heavily using scala. We use intellij CE with scala plugin.

So far everything seems to work except the debugger.

Does anyone know about how to setup debugger for scala in intellij?
Is there any good on-line resource for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends if it's a desktop or a web app, anyway this thread should be useful for you: [Debugging Scala code with simple-build-tool (sbt) and IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150776/debugging-scala-code-with-simple-build-tool-sbt-and-intellij)

Comment: it does not work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337745/intellij-idea-debug-jumps-inside-instead-of-going-over