# IntelliJ IDEA debug jumps inside instead of going over

Tags: debugging, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I use last stable SBT with Scala 2.10 and last Scala plugin in IntelliJ IDEA 12.x. And have very simple test Scala project.

I have [specs2](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/) test where I want to start my debug from. Having several breakpoints, I'm expecting going over lines,  (from one break point to another - in my test and in My code), but instead: the debbuger going somewhere inside library classes, stops there, showing me some strange sources.

That's reproducible all the time, and I have to click 2, 3, sometimes 5 times on the next-arrow-button (on debug panel) to reach next break point (in the test or in the code).

I run my test with SBT 'test-compile' action, like IntelliJ pop-up suggests.

Aldo I found [this](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/SCA/Scala+Debugger+Settings) debug settings for Scala ("Do not step into specific Scala classes"). But I have this check-box selected.

I've post an [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-5637) in IntelliJ IDEA site.

Comment: i have similar issues. breakpoints get hit more than once, cursor stays on same line when stepping and more funkyness. My project is non-sbt based though. It uses maven.

Comment: I've updated my ticket. Attached sample project and steps to reproduce. That's strange.. Actually it is blocker.. at least for me.

Comment: Have the same issue with dead cursor. And sometimes it renders very slow. Lack of IDE support makes scala just a toy..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ 15 now has support for adding breakpoints inside lambdas. See [this blog post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2015/09/02/debugging-lambdas-and-macro-expansion-extractor/) for details.