# Adding debug points in for-comprehension / partial functions

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, slick, slick-3.0

How can I add debug points to statements in for-comprehension?

```
for {
  a <- sqlQuery1()
  b <- sqlQuery2()
} yield {
  // output
}
```

I want to inspect as each of the above queries are executed, but simply adding debug points does not seem to work. The queries get executed without ever hitting debug points. I am not sure if it is a limitation of the library being used, language or IDE.

Here is my setup:

- Scala
- IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3
- Scala Plugin 1.5.200
- Library - [Slick 3.0](http://slick.typesafe.com/) (Using DBIO Actions)

---

**Update:**

**Case 1:** with slick

Debug points don't work. Confirmed that again.

**Case 2:** w/o slick

Debugger does stop at debug points. But sometimes it evaluates expressions and sometimes it does not. I have noticed following problems (in currying / anonymous functions):

1. Variable value is shown as 'Size = ?'
2. Variable value is 'Debug info unavailable'
3. Fails to evaluate expression
4. Cursor stays on the same line without highlighting anything whenever I step over (it is doing things in the background though)
5. 'Warning: No executable code found at...'

---

Actually searching without slick as keyword showed me that a lot of people have similar issues, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337745/intellij-idea-debug-jumps-inside-instead-of-going-over).

Comment: Works for me; I have the same Intellij setup.

Comment: @I.K. Are you using slick with for-comprehension? I am not sure, but I think it might be playing a role here then. It uses [reactive streams](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/akka-stream-scala).

Comment: I am able to set break points inside the `for`-comprehension. When I run the debugger it does stop inside and then I use the Intellij force into feature  to go inside the code that is inside the `for`-comprehension.

Comment: Added more info based on your update.