# Debug Gatling Scala Code in Intellij with Maven Java Project

Tags: scala, maven, debugging, intellij-idea, gatling

I didn't add a comment in this [Debug Scala Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504111/debug-scala-code-in-intellij) because in my opinion it was another setup.

I had a similiar problem with Maven instead of SBT. I used Maven because the complete Java project was built upon it and I only wanted to debug my Gatling Scala code. However I'm not able to debug the code with the IDE.

Here's what I tried:

- Clean the built `mvn clean install`
- Invalidate caches in IDEA with the menu button
- Use `println` to see whether the code is reached - worked
- Redeploy the project on the Glassfish
- Delete the generated files in the Glassfish and redeploy

This is my current setup:

- Maven 3.3.9
- Glassfish Payara 4 build 163
- IDEA 2016.3.4. built on January 31 2017
- JDK 1.8.0_51
- [Gatling 2.2.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.gatling/gatling-maven-plugin/2.2.3)
- [Scala-Maven-Plug 3.2.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.alchim31.maven/scala-maven-plugin/3.2.2)

My solution is as follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of colleague I figured out that the main class in `Engine` from the [Gatling tutorial](http://gatling.io/docs/current/extensions/maven_archetype/) can be used to debug out of Intellij.

I basically built the whole archetype and moved the following files into the corresponding folders:

- src/test/resources/gatling.conf
- src/test/scala/Engine.scala and IDEPathHelper

That did the trick for me.

Comment: How do run the tests to be able to debug them? I'm running the main func from Engine class but it stops on `com.my.package.MySimulation is the only simulation, executing it.
Select run description (optional)`

Answer (score 1):

If anybody is finding hard to this just create a logback.xml file under src/test/resources and mention the following according to your need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %logger{15} - %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
            <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>../gatling.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %logger{15} - %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <!-- Uncomment for logging ALL HTTP request and responses -->
    <!--  <logger name="io.gatling.http.ahc" level="TRACE" /> -->
    <!--   <logger name="io.gatling.http.response" level="TRACE" /> -->
    <!-- Uncomment for logging ONLY FAILED HTTP request and responses -->
    <logger name="io.gatling.http.ahc" level="DEBUG" />
    <logger name="io.gatling.http.response" level="DEBUG" />
    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```