# Remote SBT Debugging

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am using `sbt container:start shell` to start my scala application and I'm wondering how I could specify a debug port to write to, so that I can set up remote debugging in IntelliJ.

I've tried specifying something along the lines of `jvm-debug 5005` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150776/debugging-scala-code-with-simple-build-tool-sbt-and-intellij), but that caused the process to not start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export your sbt_opts:

```
 SBT_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
```

Then setup a remote debuging configuration in intellij connecting to localhost 5005