# View variable value by hovering mouse over it in debug

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to setup Idea to show variable `toString()` value when I hover a mouse over it like in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to **Preferences > Build, execution, deployment > Debugger > Data Views** and enable **show value tooltip on code selection**.

[image]

Comment: It's not nearly as smooth as VS as you have to actually select (highlight) the whole expression in order to view the value, instead of just hovering over it in VS, but certainly better than nothing.

Comment: Still doesn't work 2023

Answer (score -1):

Place a break point after your variable is assigned a value and intellij will print what value that variable has taken next to it.

[image]

Comment: Seems like I didn't understand you correctly. So all variable values are printed in debug mode on their declaration lines. But in long methods can I view them without scrolling up?

Comment: hope the picture makes it more clear, for long methods there is a debugger window which lists all the variables and their corresponding values

Comment: How did you make that green label with value to show? I tried the same with if statement but: http://screencast.com/t/Lreqa88hf I have only the first gray label near the declaration (not on screen).

Comment: it should do that automatically, have you configured your debugger?

Comment: I didn't change settings, may be it doesn't work with scala

Comment: try following this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150776/debugging-scala-code-with-simple-build-tool-sbt-and-intellij

Comment: ok, thanks, looks like I have to look on declarations or variables window. I'll wait a day before accepting in case someone has a better answer.