# how to run only one test in scalatest/playspec

Tags: intellij-idea

My `spec` file has several tests

```
"HomeController index page" should {
    "have title Welcome " in {
....
}

  "Home controller " should {
      "render homepage with csrfToken" in {
...
}
```

To run the tests in `IntelliJ`, I `right-click` on the `spec` file and select `run`. But this runs all the tests. Is there a way to select tests and run only the selected ones?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10854 could be the case.

Comment: Thanks. So placing the cursor in the test method and pressing `Shift+Ctrl+F10` does the trick. I am happy to accept your answer if you can provide it

Comment: for completeness sake, I could also create an `Edit configuration` for each method in a test class or for the entire test class. Click Edit Configuration, click + on top lefft and select ScalaTest, On right, I can mention either the entire class  (eg Myspec) or a method in the class (eg MySpec.someSpec) in the Test Class  box. I notice I can also select Class, Test Name or Regular Expression from Test Kind dropbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to run individual tests by placing the cursor inside the test method and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> or by creating the ScalaTest run/debug configuration where you can specify the test name to run.

See also [Test scopes in Scala](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-and-test-scala.html) section in the documentation:

[image: Run tests]